# Can the antiderivate of $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$ be calculated without using the iteration formula?

Tags: calculus, integration

To calculate the antiderivate of $$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$$ , we can either use the iteration formula reducing the exercise to the integral of $\ \frac{1}{x^2+1}\ $ or we can use $$(\frac{x}{x^2+1})'=\frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}$$ , but I do not see how we can get the antiderivate of $\ \frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\ $ either without any guess (If we know this antiderivate , we can express $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$ as a linear combination of $\ f(x):=\frac{1}{x^2+1}\ $ and $\ g(x):=\frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\ $ , namely $\ \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}\ $)

> How can I calculate $\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2}$ only by using intgration by parts and the substitution rule as well as other basic integration rules ? I am looking for a solution not containing a guess or the iteration formula.

Comment: Is partial fraction decomposition allowed?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, of course.

Comment: Then you can use $\dfrac{1}{x^2+1} = \dfrac{1}{2i}\biggl(\dfrac{1}{x-i} - \dfrac{1}{x+i}\biggr)$, square it, integrate, combine. Though Olivier Oloa's substitution is admittedly neater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}=\int \frac{1+x^2-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=$$

$$\arctan(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int x\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=$$

$$\arctan(x)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\left[x \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right]-\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x)+\frac{x}{ 2(1+x^2)  }+C$$

Answer (score 4):

By the change of variable
$$
x=\tan t, \quad dt= \frac{dx}{1+x^2},
$$ one gets
$$
\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}=\int\cos^2 t\:dt=\int \left(\frac12+\frac{\cos 2t}2\right)dt
$$ which is easier.

Comment: I think we have to ask the OP what he constitutes a guess. But +1 from me!

Comment: @OlivierOloa It remains to transform $\sin(2\arctan(x))$. Do you mind to work that out as well ? (I think it is not too difficult, but it would be very nice if you added that)

Comment: @Peter Yes, one may recall that $\sin(2u)=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$ with $u=\arctan x$.

Comment: OK, this is sufficient for me for an upvote :)

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For substitution method, see [How do I solve this trigonometric substitution integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025246/how-do-i-solve-this-trigonometric-substitution-integral).

For  intgration by parts,

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}=\int\dfrac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}\cdot\dfrac1{2x}\ dx$$

$$=\dfrac1{2x}\int\dfrac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx-\int\left(\int\dfrac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx\cdot \dfrac{d(1/2x)}{dx}\right)dx$$

$$=-\dfrac1{2x(1+x^2)}-\dfrac12\int\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)x^2}$$

Now $$\int\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)x^2}=\int\dfrac{(1+x^2)-x^2}{(1+x^2)x^2}dx=?$$